# Outlook Replication API

Tags: api, outlook, replication

The Outlook ReplicationAPI can used to sync with server other than MS Exchange Server?
Because i try to use it to sync with my proprietary server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in theory, you can use Replication API to [sync with any server for which there is a MAPI Transport provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192879%28office.11%29.aspx) ([some of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_Application_Programming_Interface#Service_provider_interface)). is there one for your *proprietary server*? in practice, and looking at [About the Replication API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192879%28office.11%29.aspx), i doubt that it will work with anything other than MS Exchange Server.